# How do Pokémon from entirely different species breed?

Tags: pokemon, sexuality

In the *Pokémon* universe Pokémon are known to breed with Pokémon that are completely different animals (i.e. Wailord and Skitty). How does this work?

Comment: https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pokémon_breeding

Comment: I would assume a stepladder is involved. And a Barry White album and a bottle of cheap red wine.

Comment: How do Pokémon from different species breed? *Very carefully.*

Comment: Trust us you do not wanna know about the hot skitty-on-wailord action, https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HotSkittyOnWailordAction

Comment: That is how Ditto was born.

Comment: So you are asking about the Delibirds and the Combees?

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly because Pokemon is a series aimed at children, the exact mechanics are never explained - the trivia section of the [Bulbapedia article](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding) notes that "the characters in the game make special mention of the fact that no one has seen Pokémon breed".

All that we know is that you need two Pokemon that are compatible (which generally has to do with how similar they are in various ways), and you leave them together at a Day Care. Then, some time later, they will have produced an egg.

The people at the Day Care often express surprise at the egg's production, although that could just be a case of them not wanting to discuss the details with you, who in the game is typically very young.